# If I delete music from an iPad will it affect music stored on any other iCloud-connected device?

Tags: ipad, icloud

Asking on behalf of my mother.

The music came on via iCloud syncing AFAIK so I wanted to make sure that removing it in one place wouldn't remove it somewhere else as we'll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't effect other devices as iCloud does not automatically sync music between devices other than downloading newly purchased music to all devices if you have iOS configured that way. (Settings > iTunes & App Store > automatic downloads > music "on")

That automatic download is one way and one time only not perpetual.